# Is A-GPS information downloaded by the OS or by the individual apps?

Tags: gps

I use different apps that work with GPS on my device. One of the apps has a "download A-GPS information" button to quickly find satellites.

Does that mean that apps need to trigger the A-GPS download themselves? Or does the Android OS handle A-GPS download whenever GPS is turned on?

Comment: A-GPS data comes pre-loaded with the OS. GPS Toolbox allows you to download specific A-GPS data that has more satellites in your region in it but less for other regions. It works wonders and helps with long TTF's (time to fix)

Comment: @GiantTree Sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The OS manage the A-GPS information, but you can ask to force a new data download to update it.

Andorid do it automatically when A-GPS data expires.